# Can you show the following property of the Logarithm function?

Tags: calculus, functions, optimization

For every $a > 0$ and $T \geq 1$, show that

$\sup_{1 \leq x \leq T} x log\left( 1 + \frac{1}{x+a-1} \right) = \max \left(\log \left( 1 + \frac{1}{a}\right),T\log \left( 1 + \frac{1}{T+a-1}\right)\right)$.

Essentially, to prove that the maximum occurs at the boundary ? I tried all the usual tricks of playing with the derivatives, but to no avail. Any help or suggestions ?